# SSRS - change background color based on a string

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, background, background-color

I have a report with a Date column shown below, starting with Day of the week -

```
Wednesday, 01/01/2020
Thursday,  01/02/2020
Friday,    01/03/2020
Saturday,  01/04/2020
Sunday,    01/05/2020
Monday,    01/06/2020
Tuesday,   01/07/2020
```

I would like to change the background color (fill) of the row if the Day is a Saturday or Sunday. Can you please suggest a way to do this.

Thank you!
JHegde

Comment: Are you returning the day of the week in your report dataset or just the date?

Comment: I am returning the day of the week as well. 
Day of the week, Date. 

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the cells you want to change colors and use this expression in the Properties option (BackgroundColor) to change the fill of the textbox:

```
=IIF(weekday(Fields!Date.Value) = 1, "Green", IIF(weekday(Fields!Date.Value) = 7, "Green", "Red"))
```

Change **Fields!Date.Value** to reference your field.

"Green" = Weekend color

"Red" = Weekday color

Comment: Should you need to colour each day differently, consider using a `switch` expression, which would be more readable with the additional logic.